# Lazy loading in sidebar - not working, missing something trivial

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I seem to be missing something very trivial in here...
I can't get lazyload to work on the sidebar on the right. Any guesses?

here is the link:

[APM v2](http://arquitectospelomundo.com/v2/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the lazy load just after you set the sidebar innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
$("img.lazy").lazyload({         
  effect : "fadeIn",
  container: $("#side_bar")
});
```

Comment: If tried using on document.ready but with the same results so far :/

Comment: I believe there is an incompatibility between body onload and document.ready... but I need to run initialize() on body load, perhaps there is an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I would have rather put the initialize() in document.ready for when the DOM is fully loaded since you only creating map markers. @BMM

Comment: Hm... i've placed both initialize() and the lazyload script in 2 document.ready functions, but still function 2 is not "lazy-loading" the images it should... :/

Comment: Thank you! This helped and it now works (however, I need to first scroll the div to make the images appear, otherwise they will be gray – it can be seen at http://www.arquitectospelomundo.com/v2. Thanks once again!